# How to send a message from sync thread into async task in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, channel, rust-tokio

I have a program that is already written in synchronous style, and it uses some necessary libraries that require it. But I think that it may benefit from using `async` features for some of its functions. So I would want to see how I can send messages between those parts via channel where sending path is synchronous and receiving part is in an `async` task.
There are, for example, MPSC channels both in `std::sync::mpsc` and in `tokio::sync::mpsc` which look confusingly similar and do not seem to support the case I want.

Comment: Why do you believe tokio channels don't support your case? They have both sync and async send and receive methods.

Comment: @user4815162342 Mine is a non-question only if you already know the answer. I could not find the right API right away. Therefore asking.

Comment: Didn't say it was a non-question, I was just wondering if there is more to your requirements than is apparent. You seem to be aware that you need channels with both sync and async interface, and tokio channels are an example of those. Is there a reason why you didn't proceed with them?

Answer (score -1):

`tokio` documentation has a tutorial section covering such cases [here](https://tokio.rs/tokio/topics/bridging). There is an example of sending a message over a channel exactly for this case in "Sending messages" section.

Below is a slightly modified example that uses multi-threaded runtime.

Dependencies in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "sync"] }
```

`src/main.rs` is:

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

type Message = u64;

fn main() {
    let rt = Runtime::new().expect("Start tokio runtime.");
    let (sender_async, mut receiver_async) = mpsc::channel::<Message>(10);

    rt.spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let x = receiver_async.recv().await;
            if x == None { break; }
            println!("Recv async channel: {:?}", x);
        }
    });

    let mut message_id = 0;
    loop {
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(600));
        match sender_async.blocking_send(message_id) {
            Err(e) => println!("Async send err: {}", e),
            Ok(()) => println!("Async sent."),
        }
        message_id += 1;
    }
}
```

So `blocking_send` method of `tokio::sync::mpsc` can be used on the synchronous side.

Comment: "which turns out a bit more complex but also doable" - no, it is not (I mean, it is, but your code is not the way). Your code works by luck as the data is always in the channel. In more complex scenarios it won't work (also, your code could benefit from `let-else`.

Comment: In which case it will not? There is a case for handling empty channel. In fact most of the time the channel is empty.

Comment: Except that the case for handling an empty channel _doesn't work_. If you'll ever encounter an empty channel, you'll be stuck forever ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f255ca9233fdf99b21feedce9540ce2a)). The future is never waked up. It didn't happen. Only by luck.

Comment: I see, it is not polled again. Have to `Waker::wake`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman OK, removed the std::sync::mpsc example. Thanks!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I did make it work by having a Arc<Mutex<Option<Waker>>> variable. Now I admit that it is a lot more cumbersome to implement correctly, so it makes sense to prefer what tokio has already...

Comment: You can make it work with `Waker` alone, no need for `Arc<Mutex<Option>>`. But it's still not the correct way. It'll be a busy loop, consuming 100% CPU. The correct way, if for some reason you're forced into `std::sync::mpsc` (for example, because some library API uses it), is to use `tokio`'s [`spawn_blocking()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html) and call `recv()` there.

Comment: No in my code it is not a busy loop: Waker::wake is invoked when data is ready. The actual problem I could not resolve was that Waker is not available until Future is polled there was a place where the code could panic.
I wanted std::sync example, in order to understand what is needed to implement such a thing, since reading tokio source code is not very helpful.
Yes, example using tokio::sync::mpsc is what I kept in the answer.

Comment: How, exactly? `std::sync::mpsc` has no way to inform the future's waker when it is ready. Do you want to implement a channel yourself? If not, why would you want to know how it works? If you do, tokio's version is async-first and the sync version just block on the async ones. Doing the opposite is generally not possible.

Comment: Here is the corrected version that uses std::sync https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=20bce366bf133024c397981443b842df
I think I've got what I wanted to learn from this. Unless there are some further problems :) Thank you!

Comment: This works, but is so messy that I wouldn't call it "correct". And if you can share things beside the channel you can make it work much more easily with [`Notify`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Notify.html). Or just use `tokio`'s channel, since I cannot imagine a situation where you can share something except the channel but you are still forced to use std's channels.

Comment: I think you do not understand the purpose of this exercise for me. I have already said it is messy.

Comment: That could be. I don't think you told me what is the purpose of this exercise for you.